# Tire + Elastic Search - Forcing Import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, elasticsearch, tire

In the tire gem's README, I see they propose two ways to import a model:

```
rake environment tire:import CLASS='Article'
rake environment tire:import CLASS='Article' FORCE=true
```

I can appreciate that the FORCE=true will delete the index before reindexing, but what is the benefit in doing so?

Answer (score 4):

Deleting and recreating the index from scratch is useful mainly when you change the model mapping during development.

Comment: So if you don't set FORCE=1 and you change the mapping, then what happens if you reimport the model?

Comment: The new mapping isn't applied. You have to manually update it with `Mymodel.index.mapping({... new mapping...})`.